# How do I omit record that contain zeros in certain fields?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that prints records from the database but I do not understand how to omit those records that contain zeros for certain fields. The fields that may contain zeros are `townhalls`, `org_pressconf`, `rep_doors`, `vol_doors`, `contacts`, `phones`, `coffeehours`, `newsarticles`, and `mediahits`. If each of the fields I mentioned above are equal to zero, how do I write the query to omit those results?

```
// START Organizer Report   
// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  
Concat(last_name, ' , ', first_name) as Representative, 
sum(townhalls) as Townhalls, 
sum(org_pressconf) as PressConference, 
sum(rep_doors) as RepDoors, 
sum(vol_doors) as VolunteerDoors, 
sum(contacts) as Contacts, 
sum(phones) as Phones, 
sum(coffeehours) as CoffeeHours, 
sum(newsarticles) as NewsArticles, 
sum(mediahits) as MediaHits 
FROM reports 
join representatives on reports.rep = representatives.id 
join users on reports.username = users.username 
WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND role = 'organizer'
Group By representative Order By representative;");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}


$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h2>Organizer Report <small>($from to $to)</small></h2>";
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>
<tr>";

// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";

// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}

mysql_free_result($result);

    echo "</table>\n";
// END Organizer Report
```

Comment: `WHERE townhalls != 0 AND ... != 0 AND ... ` ?

Comment: `HAVING  Townhalls > 0 AND PressConference > 0 AND ... `

Comment: I think filtering before the `GROUP BY` (with `WHERE`) would be the more efficient variant, since it would reduce the amount of rows to be checked for grouping.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's so obvious now I feel ridiculous. I was apparently thinking too hard about how to solve it. If there was an emoticon for shooting oneself in the head I would add it here. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following HAVING clause if you want to omit rows where all of those fields equal zero.

```
HAVING (townhalls + org_pressconf + rep_doors + vol_doors + contacts + phones + coffeehours + newsarticles + mediahits) > 0
```